# Generate Random String in java

Tags: java, string, random, secure-random

I'm trying to generate a string between capital A-Z in java using Secure Random. Currently I'm able to generate an alphanumeric string with special characters but I want a string with only upper case alphabets.

```
  public String createRandomCode(int codeLength, String id){   
     char[] chars = id.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
        return output ;
    }
```

The input parameters are length of the output string & id whhich is alphanumeric string.Can't understand what modifications to make to the above code to generate only upper case alphabet string. Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method randomly selects characters out of the `id` argument. If you want those to only be uppercase letters, then pass a string with those characters:

```
String randomCode = createRandomCode(length, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

**EDIT** If you want to avoid duplicates, you can't just select characters at random. You'll want to shuffle them and pick out the first `n` characters:

```
public String createRandomCode(int codeLength, String id) {   
    List<Character> temp = id.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(temp, new SecureRandom());
    return temp.stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .limit(codeLength)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

**EDIT 2** Just for fun, here's another way to implement the original random code generator (allowing duplicates):

```
public static String createRandomCode(int codeLength, String id) {
    return new SecureRandom()
            .ints(codeLength, 0, id.length())
            .mapToObj(id::charAt)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: What changes do I need to make in the above code so that the string contains no repeating alphabets??

Answer (score 3):

Here is generator that I wrote and use:

```
public class RandomGenerator {
    private static final String characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static String generateRandom(int length) {
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        if (length <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String length must be a positive integer");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append(characters.charAt(random.nextInt(characters.length())));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

in `numChars` string you can put any characters you want to be included. `int length` parameter is the length of generated random string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example method that uses the int range for characters A to Z (also this method avoids duplicate characters in the `String`)  :

```
public String createRandomCode(final int codeLength) {

    int min = 65;// A
    int max = 90;// Z


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new SecureRandom();

    for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {

        Character c;

        do {

            c = (char) (random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);

        } while (sb.indexOf(c.toString()) > -1);

        sb.append(c);
    }

    String output = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(output);
    return output;
}
```

The range part comes from this topic : [Generating random integers in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)